# Uploading images to mysql using php form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, image-uploading

I have this form to upload pictures to my mysql database:

```
<h4>Add Photo</h4>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
        $caption   = $_POST['caption'];
        $albumID   = $_POST['album'];
        $file      = $_FILES ['file']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES ['file']['type'];
        $file_size = $_FILES ['file']['size'];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES ['file']['tmp_name'];
        $random_name = rand();

        if (empty($file)){
            echo "Please enter a file <br>";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');
            mysqli_query(
                $mysqli,
                "INSERT INTO photos (caption, image_url, date_taken, imageID) "
                . "VALUES('"
                . addslashes($caption) . "', '"
                . $random_name . ".jpeg', NOW(), ?)"
            );
            echo "Photo successfully uploaded!<br>";
        }
    }
    ?>

    Caption: <br>
    <input type="text" name="caption">
    <br><br>

    Select Album: <br>
    <select name="album">
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM albums");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $albumID = $row['albumID'];
        $title   = $row['title'];
        echo "<option value='$albumID'>$title</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    Select Photo: <br>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I can successfully upload pictures to the 'uploads' folder on my sever, however nothing is added to the 'photos' table on my database.
The schema for my photos folder is: 
caption, image_url, date_taken, imageID

is there something I am doing wrong with the structure? mysqli code?
any help will be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're using `?` as a placeholder in your values. That's [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) syntax and you're not preparing anything for it. Add `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()` and find out why it's failing. You'll see the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Fred -ii- mentioned, the problem is that you're using a "?" as the value for the column imageID, but you're not using prepared statements. You're not checking for errors, but if you did you'd get something like:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line xx

Also, you're using addslashes to get user data into the query, which is unsafe (you should use [mysqli_real_escape_string instead](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).

A good solution to both problems would be to use prepared statements. You'd do something like this instead:

```
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');
    $ret = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO photos (caption, image_url, date_taken)
    VALUES(?, ?, NOW())");
    $filename = $random_name + ".jpeg";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ret, "ss", $caption, $filename);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($ret);
    echo "Photo successfully uploaded!<br>";
```

**Update**: As the id is autogenerated, I removed the column from the query entirely.

Comment: [Which  is what I said 16 mins. prior to this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198983/uploading-images-to-mysql-using-php-form#comment46610492_29198983). So, who knows what the OP wants to use for their `imageID` column.

Comment: You're right, and I added a deserved reference. It's true that we don't know what that column might be, but adding a full example so he can see how the code would look using prepared statements can be useful.

Comment: We'll see what the OP has to say. Hard to say if they've seen your answer/my comment. Time will tell ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! my imageID column is an integer and I have set is as auto_increment. How should I proceed with the code? is it the same or do I need to alter the code you posted? @Anxo

Comment: I updated the example with how it should look. Basically, you just have to remove the column from the query. Not mentioning it means it gets the default value, which is the auto-generated one.

Comment: @Anxo can i ask you another question? I have 2 tables right now, photos and albums, the schema for albums is: title, date_created, date_modified, albumID (primary key). How do I create a third table that related albumID to imageID (from photos), in order to let a photo be on multiple albums? (If I put albumID in photos, a photo would not be able to appear on multiple albums)

Comment: You really should make a new question, but... for [many-to-many relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29), you have to create a new table with foreign keys for each of the sides of the relationship. That means that in your case, it should be something like: album_photos(albumID, imageID).